# HttpClient 502 Bad Gateway Async only

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am having trouble with calling a web service asynchronously. I have called it synchronously without error hundreds of times inside a loop, but when I call it asynchronously, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error, usually after about 250 asynchronous calls. As you can see, I've tried waiting 50ms with `Thread.Sleep()` and retrying up to 5 times per record. The `404 Not Found` error is expected when I'm unable to validate a record. My framework is netstandard2.0.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<OriginalRecord> originalRecords = new List<OriginalRecord>();
            originalRecords.Add(new OriginalRecord()
            {
                Id = "IdOne",
                Foo = "fooOne"
            });
            originalRecords.Add(new OriginalRecord()
            {
                Id = "IdTwo",
                Foo = "fooTwo"
            });

            List<RecordValidation> unvalidatedRecords = new List<RecordValidation>();

            try
            {
                RecordValidator validator = new RecordValidator("myAccessToken", "myBarId");
                var task = validator.ValidateRecordsAsync(originalRecords.Select(r => r.Id).ToList());
                task.Wait();
                unvalidatedRecords = task.Result;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    public class RecordValidator
    {
        public RecordValidator(string AccessToken, string BarId)
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("MessageService/3.1");

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AccessToken);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/hal+json");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

            barId = BarId;
        }

        private static HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
        
        public string barId { get; set; }

        public async Task<List<RecordValidation>> ValidateRecordsAsync(List<string> Records)
        {
            List<Task<RecordValidation>> tasks = new List<Task<RecordValidation>>();

            foreach (var record in Records)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ValidateRecordAsync(record)));
            }

            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            return results.Where(r => !r.Validated).ToList();
        }

        private async Task<RecordValidation> ValidateRecordAsync(string Record)
        {
            string url = $"https://data.somewebapp.com/api/bar/{barId}/record/{Uri.EscapeDataString(Record)}";
            int retries = 0;
            bool success = false;
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            try
            {

                do
                {
                    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        success = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(50);
                        retries++;
                    }
                } while (retries < 5 && !success);


                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RecordValidation>(responseString);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output.RecordId))
                    output.Validated = true;
                return output;
            }

            catch (HttpRequestException ex) when (ex.Message == "Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).")
            {
                return new RecordValidation()
                {
                    RecordId = Record,
                    Validated = false
                };
            }

            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    public class RecordValidation
    {
        public RecordValidation()
        {
            RecordId = string.Empty;
            Validated = false;
        }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string RecordId { get; set; }

        public bool Validated { get; set; }
    }

    public class OriginalRecord
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 502 response is an actual response. Your HTTP request succeeded, and the server returned a 502 response. It's likely because you're hitting the server too fast and hard and it's cutting you off.

When you do it synchronously, it will send the request and wait for a response before moving on to the next one.

But in this loop:

```
foreach (var record in Records)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ValidateRecordAsync(record)));
}
```

You're creating a new thread for each request, which has the effect of sending every request almost simultaneously. Clearly the server does not like that.

You don't need to create a new thread for each request. You could start them asynchronously without `Task.Run()`, like:

```
foreach (var record in Records)
{
    tasks.Add(ValidateRecordAsync(record));
}
```

That will slow it just a little bit, but not much. This would run `ValidateRecordAsync()` on the same thread up until the HTTP request is sent before moving to the next iteration of the loop and starting the next. But that might still be too fast for the server, since you're still sending all the requests before the previous is complete.

You will likely have to throttle your requests. If you want it to be as fast as possible, you can find out how many requests the web service will allow you to send, you can tailor your code to the web service. Otherwise, you'll just be guessing.

You could send, say 10 at a time and add a pause in between.

```
foreach (var record in Records)
{
    tasks.Add(ValidateRecordAsync(record));
    if (tasks.Count % 10 == 0) await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Or wait until those 10 complete before moving on:

```
foreach (var record in Records)
{
    tasks.Add(ValidateRecordAsync(record));
    if (tasks.Count % 10 == 0) await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

You can call `Task.WhenAll` on the same list of tasks multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code. I was hoping this wasn't the case, but here we are. I think I'll return the `HttpResponseMessage.HttpStatusCode`, and continue to iterate over those that return 502, with a delay between each batch.

Comment: Were you able to get 502 error response in ```HttpResponseMessage.HttpStatusCode``` ?

Answer (score 1):

250 parallel calls are way too much. It should be rather 10-30. Default max number of concurrent requests for the C# Http client is 10, so if you aren't overriding that value, it doesn't make sense to try to open more than 10 socket connections simultaneously. Also, keep in mind, 502 status is most likely returned by reverse proxy, which means you aren't really hitting the web API, proxy is telling you "slow down, I cannot handle that anymore". So in your case, it's not really `HttpClient` issue, otherwise, you would get some exception, like `SocketException` due to socket exhaustion, which you aren't probably getting due to `HttpClient` limitting concurrency to 10. Also, you have plenty of thread blocking code, like `Thread.Sleep()` or `task.Wait()`, change your main method signature to `static async Task Main()` and use `await` everywhere, otherwise, you will run into other types of issues, like thread exhaustion

Comment: Since I'm only using one `HttpClient`, and not overriding the number of concurrent requests, does it still make sense to throttle it elsewhere? If so, would you mind providing an example?

Comment: Yes, sure you can take a look [here](https://josef.codes/c-sharp-throttle-http-requests-concurrent/)

Comment: thanks I'll give the `TransformBlock` a try